# Surface::setbuffersDimensions Log being spammed

Tags: android, android-debug

I have built an Android app that is working fine and as expected with a tablet: Acer. 7-inch API 21.

I recently got a new tablet: Acer. 10-inch API 22.

Now I am getting my logs spammed with this line.

```
04-12 18:23:27.371 8776-9082/com.callbell.callbell D/Surface: Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x7f9aa44000,w=800,h=1280)
```

and the screen will freeze and go blank at random intervals. I have not seen any errors in the log and the only reference I can find to this log line is here

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/fe94bd262bc0a33d709aee8fb70c1369656b479b/libs/gui/Surface.cpp

**UPDATE**
I've tried this on a few devices with varying success.

NO ISSUES:

Samsung Galaxy Tab 7"

Samsung Galaxy Tab 10"

Acer Iconia 8"

ISSUES:

Acer Iconia 10"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These log come when we have EditText with cursor, And that cursor blink is responsible to redraw screen.

Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x7f4ccc7c00,w=1080,h=1920)
D/OpenGLRenderer: WorkerThread 0x7f7c07f000 running

When I did

```
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

these logs were gone.

So when studio screen become spam with these logs, Its an alert for developer to check UI draw pattern.

Comment: on my device Doogee X5 animated progress bar also causes this spam

Answer (score 5):

This log means that something on your screen is being redrawn.
It is shown only on few devices, but whatever the device you are using, you can enable 'hardware layers updates' or 'gpu view updates'  in developer options and you'll see flashed zone, which is being redrawn.
Moreover, if the issue exists on one device, it's likely that it exists on others too.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else finds this issue, make sure that you don't have something like a ProgressBar or so that you're not stopping from rendering after the WebView has finished loading.
In Xamarin.Android, I had to override OnPageFinished, from the WebViewClient, and set `progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;`. There's also a link in there to a GitHub repo (not mine) that has some other WebViewClient override implementations:

```
        public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
        {
            view.LoadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }

        //More overrides: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/MonoIO/UI/MapFragment.cs
        public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
        {
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            view.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }

    }
```