# Surface::setBuffersDimensions spammed with android libdgdx app

Tags: java, android, libgdx

When I debug my Android app, I find the following in the logcat:

```
    07-02 04:49:52.686 2734-2771/fr.fosse.deepDrill.androidGame.AndroidLauncher D/Surface: Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x7f8b60fe00,w=1080,h=1776)
    07-02 04:49:52.703 2734-2771/fr.fosse.deepDrill.androidGame.AndroidLauncher D/Surface: Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x7f8b60fe00,w=1080,h=1776)
    07-02 04:49:52.720 2734-2771/fr.fosse.deepDrill.androidGame.AndroidLauncher D/Surface: Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x7f8b60fe00,w=1080,h=1776)
```

How can I remove them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lokesh Tiwari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2080965/lokesh-tiwari) answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586416/surfacesetbuffersdimensions-log-being-spammed):

> These log come when we have EditText with cursor, And that cursor
>   blink is responsible to redraw screen.
>   When I did
>
> `android:cursorVisible="false" these logs were gone.`
>
> So when studio screen become spam with these logs, Its an alert for
>   developer to check UI draw pattern.

Hope this helps !

Comment: What if there is no EditText in my layout.

Comment: That's no reason to downvote :) just trying to help!

Comment: And there is no reason to answer a duplicate question, you can  do it in comment section :)

Comment: It wasn't marked as duplicate back then ;)